# Simple Extending Native JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, native

Take a look at the code bellow, it's pretty self-explanatory. How do I modify the 'replaceAt' function to get the desired results?

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (at) {
    return this.substring(0, at) + this.substring(at+1, this.length);   
}

var str = "webmaster";

var x = str.replaceAt(2);
console.log(x); // should return "b"
console.log(str); // should return "wemaster"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Look at the comments in the last two lines.

Comment: You have provided us with what you _expect_, but then what _happened_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, strings are immutable.

One other approach would be to return an object or array containing the replaced character, and the new string. Then assign the values to the variables 'x' and 'str', respectively:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (at) {
    return {
       x: this.substring(at+1, at),
       str: this.substring(0, at) + this.substring(at+1, this.length)
    }   
};

var str = "webmaster";
var result = str.replaceAt(2);
var x = result.x;
str = result.str;

console.log(x);
console.log(str);
```

However, utilizing the ES6 feature 'destructuring', you can in fact bring it down to a oneliner:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (at) {
    return [
       this.substring(at+1, at),
       this.substring(0, at) + this.substring(at+1, this.length)
    ]
};

var str = "webmaster";
[x, str] = str.replaceAt(2);

console.log(x);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: How come the native js function shift can do something similar: var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var x = fruits.shift();    

console.log(fruits); // returns ["Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
console.log(x); // returns 'Banana'

Comment: This is because an array is mutable.
You can pass an array to a function and modifiy it (add, delete items, etc).
This will also update the array outside of the function because it is the same instance of that array.

Strings, however, are immutable, you cannot remove characters from it, neither add characters to it. Function like .substring(), .toUpperCase(), etc do not modifiy the source string: They return a completely new string.